# Do I need cordova/phonegap when using phoneGap build

Tags: cordova

I wanted to know if I need to install and include the cordova/phonegap JavaScript in my app if I,m using phonegap build for building app ?

Answer (score 1):

No you dont need to install `cordova/phonegap javascript` if you are using phonegap build to build your application.

But you have to include phonegap.js in every html page you are including in your project.

like-

```
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

Phonegap build will take care of this js. You dont need to install. Just include above tag in head of every HTML page.

All HTMl pages js files, css make them wrap in one zip file and build that zip using phonegap build.

Comment: include the phonegap.js even if I don't have the js file for the required platforms.

Comment: you dont need to have that js. Phonegap build take care of that. You just have to include above tag and thats all, and just build it using phonegap build.